# How to make container class in PHP

Tags: php, functions, css

so, i have this part of code from a custom_functions.php that has classes, now i want to make a container to those classes, but i do not know how to do that in php.

```
if ($slide_title) {
            $strret .= '<a class="'.$slide_linkurl.'"><h2>'.$slide_title.'</h2></a>';
            $strret .= '<p>'.$str.'</p>'; 
            $strret .= '<a href="'.$slide_linkurl.'" class="da-link">'.$slide_linktext.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using below code.

```
 if ($slide_title) {
    $strret .= '<div class="container">';
                $strret .= '<a class="'.$slide_linkurl.'"><h2>'.$slide_title.'</h2></a>';
                $strret .= '<p>'.$str.'</p>'; 
                $strret .= '<a href="'.$slide_linkurl.'" class="da-link">'.$slide_linktext.'</a>'; 
    $strret .= '</div>';

    }
```

Comment: ahhh, you are amazing :)

Comment: If this works for you, Please mark this answer as correct.